# Rainfall index and water crisis in Brazil

Tags: climate, amazon

With the absence of flying rivers, the southeast will return to its natural state condemned by the latitude it occupies: desert

In the latitude of southeastern Brazil is desert all over the world, Atacama in Chile, Kalahari in Africa and Outback in Australia. For a long time INPE tried to unravel what prevented the Brazilian southeast from following its natural desert course, then with the construction of the Amazon Tall Tower Observatory (which is the highest building in all of South America) it was possible to answer: the rivers Amazon flyers.

Brazil is breaking the record for deforestation in the Amazon. With the growing deforestation in the Amazon, the rainfall cycle in the southeast (and not just the southeast) is affected immediately. If the Amazon ends today there is no rain as of today.

Deforestation in the Amazon certainly contributes largely to global warming, but before that it impacts our rain immediately. For those who are deniers of global warming and for those who are insensitive to deforestation in the Amazon, is it a good idea to comment on flying rivers? Will Brazil really sink without this phenomenon? I would like an answer, thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what a "flying river" is supposed to be?

Comment: @Erik It's the transport of atmospheric moisture southwards from the equatorial Amazon, a major source of precipitable water for the Parana basin, plus it's linked to ideas about land-atmosphere moisture recycling. http://riosvoadores.com.br/english